# Vim Javascript indenting broken for function in object property

Tags: javascript, vim, auto-indent

I've already tried several indentation solutions, including vim-javascript and many combinations of `cindent`, `smartindent`, etc. I can't find any solution which will properly indent in the following case:

```
Package.funcRequiringObject({
    foo: "1",
    bar: "2",
    foobar: function() {
        // ... code ...
    }
});
```

That's what I want. What I get is:

```
Package.... {
    ....
    foobar: function() {
                // ... code ...
            }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Install this plugin https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript

Comment: actually the current version looks better to me @_@

Comment: @elclanrs I already tried that. As I mentioned. Thanks, though!

Comment: @user3678068 heh. Thanks. Not when `foobar` is actually some 20 character long function name, adding 20 extra characters to the indent...

Comment: I have that plugin installed and my indentation works perfectly, check [my vimrc](https://github.com/elclanrs/elclanrs_vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc)

Comment: Holy jeez, that's a lot of plugins! Thanks, I'll try to figure out what the issue is. Is there anything in particular I have to do to get vim to reset indentation stuff? Besides sourcing vimrc?

Comment: @samson, indenting is mostly unrelated to your vimrc: it's filetype-dependant so you'll either need to do `:e` on your current buffer or restart vim.

Comment: @romainl thanks. I _do_ need to source vimrc to get changes to my indentation settings to take place, though, right? I guess I can change the settings just on the current buffer to test it?

Comment: @samson what did you change in your vimrc?

Comment: @romainl you know, `filteype plugin indent on` --> `filetype indent on` and back again, added / removed `set nocindent smartindent`, added / removed the `vim-javascript` Bundle, and called `BundleInstall`/`PluginClean`, etc... (I'm using Vundle to handle plugins)